# How to properly bind multiple ViewModels when using DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I'm trying to write a simple dialog that would accept a value in a SpinEdit or a text in a TextEdit. I'm using multiple VMs and I made a selector that should view a proper control based on the logic in the c++/cli file.

XAML:

```
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:asd"
       Title="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneTime}"

       <dx:DXWindow.Resources>

              <DataTemplate x:Key="TInputValueVM" DataType="{x:Type local:TInputValueVM}">
             <dxe:SpinEdit Height="23" Width="200"
                           Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}" 
                           MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}" />

          </DataTemplate>

          <DataTemplate x:Key="TInputTextVM" DataType="{x:Type local:TInputTextVM}">
             <dxe:TextEdit Height="23" Width="200"
                           Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           MaskType="RegEx" Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=OneWay}"
                           MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}"/>
          </DataTemplate>

          <local:PropertyDataTemplateSelector  x:Key="templateSelector"
             DataTemplate_Value="{StaticResource TInputValueVM}"
             DataTemplate_Text="{StaticResource TInputTextVM}" />

       </dx:DXWindow.Resources>


       <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" >
             <Label x:Uid="Label" MinHeight="24" MinWidth="60" Content="Value" />
             <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Whoami}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
          </StackPanel>

          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Uid="OKCancel_Buttons" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
             <Button Height="23" x:Name="OK_Button" Click="OK_Click" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="95" />
             <Button Height="23" x:Name="Cancel_Button" Click="Cancel_Click" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="95" />
          </StackPanel>

       </Grid>
```

In c# I have a base VM and two VMS that extend it, one for values and one for text. The rest of the properties stay the same.

C#

```
namespace asd
{
   public class TInputBaseVM : ViewModelBase
   {
      private string m_sTitle;
      private string m_sMask;
      private int m_nInputLenght;
      private string m_sWhoami;

      public TInputBaseVM(string A_sTitle, string A_sMask, int A_nInputLength)
      {
         m_sTitle = A_sTitle;
         m_sMask = A_sMask;
         m_nInputLenght = A_nInputLength;
      }

      protected string Title
      {
         get { return m_sTitle; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_sTitle, value, () => Title); }
      }
      protected string Mask
      {
         get { return m_sMask; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_sMask, value, () => Mask); }
      }

      protected int InputLength
      {
         get { return m_nInputLenght; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_nInputLenght, value, () => InputLength); }
      }

      protected string Whoami
      {
         get { return m_sWhoami; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_sWhoami, value, () => Whoami); }
      }
   }

   public class TInputValueVM : TInputBaseVM
   {
      public TInputValueVM(string A_sTitle, string A_sMask, int A_nInputLength, double A_nValue) : base(A_sTitle, A_sMask, A_nInputLength)
      {
         Value = A_nValue;
         Whoami = "Value";
      }

      private double m_nValue;
      public double Value
      {
         get { return m_nValue; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_nValue, value, () => Value); }
      }
   }

   public class TInputTextVM : TInputBaseVM
   {
      public TInputTextVM(string A_sTitle, string A_sMask, int A_nInputLength, string A_sValue) : base(A_sTitle, A_sMask, A_nInputLength)
      {
         Value = A_sValue;
         Whoami = "Text";
      }

      private string m_sValue;
      public string Value
      {
         get { return m_sValue; }
         set { SetProperty(ref m_sValue, value, () => Value); }
      }
   }

   public class PropertyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
      public DataTemplate DataTemplate_Value { get; set; }
      public DataTemplate DataTemplate_Text { get; set; }

      public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
      {
         var selector = item as string;

         if(selector == "Value")
            return DataTemplate_Value;
         return DataTemplate_Text;
      }
   }

}
```

In c++/cli I create an object of a proper VM and I'd like the WPF to automatically update the view to either spinedit or textedit, however I'm not sure how to properly bind the properties from the C#. If I explicitly type 'Value' in the Content property of the ContentControl then it displays the spinEdit but I don't know how to bind it so it automatically takes the correct property.

EDIT: I'm adding c++/cli code to show how I choose different VMs

C++/cli:

```
bool TSignalNumberPositionDialogCLR::StartDialog(TSignalNumberPositionSupport& A_Attributes, HWND A_hwndParent, LPTSTR String)
{
   try
   {
      TInputValueVM ^oExchange_Value;
      TInputTextVM ^oExchange_Text;

      int inputFormat = A_Attributes.GetInputFormat();

      if(inputFormat)
         oExchange_Text = gcnew TInputTextVM(gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetTitle()), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetMask()),
            A_Attributes.GetInputLength(), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetInitialText()));
      else
         oExchange_Value = gcnew TInputValueVM(gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetTitle()), gcnew System::String(A_Attributes.GetMask()),
            A_Attributes.GetInputLength(), A_Attributes.GetInitialValue());


      Dialogs::TSignalNumberPositionDialog^ dialog = gcnew Dialogs::TSignalNumberPositionDialog();

      if(inputFormat)
         dialog->DataContext = oExchange_Text;
      else
         dialog->DataContext = oExchange_Value;

      dialog->ShowDialog();

      if(dialog->DialogResult)
      {
         CString nValue;

         if(inputFormat)
            nValue = oExchange_Text->Value;
         else
            nValue = ((Decimal)oExchange_Value->Value).ToString("F2", CultureInfo::InvariantCulture);

         A_Attributes.UpdateValue(nValue, String, A_Attributes.GetInputLength());
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }
   catch(Exception^ e)
   {
      e;
   }
}
```

based on the 'inputFormat' variable I want to display different controls in the dialog.

EDIT: Based on @Clemens comments I got rid of the selector sectionand the x:Key property in the DataTemplates. I changed the content opf the Content property to Content="{Binding}" and it somehow works. The moment I create a VM it selects the correct one.

Comment: `Content="{Binding Path=Whoami}"` and the ContentTemplateSelector don't seem to make sense. When you assign or bind an object to the Content property of a ContentControl, the control automatically select an appropriate ContentTemplate via the DataTemplate's DataType, i.e. one that matches the Content type.

Comment: @Clemens So what would I need to do? delete the whole selector section and bind what exactly in the Content property or ContentControl?

Comment: As said, the ContentTemplate is automatically selected according to the type of the Content. If you bind Content to an object of type `MyClass`, the DataTemplate with `DataType"{x:Type local:MyClass}"` and without a `x:Key` is chosen.

Comment: @Clemens But I have two VMs and two DataTemplates. If I define one DT as     DataType"{x:Type local:TInputValueVM}"  and the second DT as     DataType"(x:Type local:TInputTextVM}"  then what do I bind the ControlContent's Content property to?

Comment: The appropriate view model, for example a property CurrentVM like `Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"`. CurrentVM returns either a TInputValueVM or a TInputTextVM.

Comment: @Clemens I deleted the x:Key properties from DTs and left the content as Content="{Binding}" and it works perfectly. Although I have no idea why...

Comment: Simply because the framework provides this magic. This would already have been the solution of your previous question, but you did not respond to my comment there.

Comment: @Clemens This is truly magic. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment. Let me improve my answer. As you are facing issue in VM selection. so plesae concentrate how I assigned VM to datatemplate. Although it is done in very basic way, you can handle it if you you are using MVVM packages. 
I have created 2 data template and 2 vms and each vm is bound to datatemplate. To verify, I have a combobox, which will select datatemplate based on selected value.

Here is Sample VM

```
public class VM : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    private SolidColorBrush background;

    public string Title { get => title; set { title = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    public SolidColorBrush Background { get => background; set { background = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class VM1: VM
{
    public VM1()
    {
        Title = "This is VM1";
        Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}

public class VM2: VM
{
    public VM2()
    {
        Title = "This is VM2";
        Background = Brushes.Orange;
    }
}
```

Now check for resources

```
<local:VM1 x:Key="VM1"/>
    <local:VM2 x:Key="VM2"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT1">
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource VM1}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DT2">
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource VM2}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Background="{Binding Background}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="contentStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="Template1">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DT1}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="Template2">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DT2}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and finally I have combobox and content control just to verify

```
    <ComboBox Name="cmbo"/>

        <ContentControl  Style="{StaticResource contentStyle}"/>
```

where  cmbo.ItemsSource = new List { "Template1", "Template2" };

Hope you got the point

Comment: Do I define that in the xaml? I have added 

        this.DataContext = this;

In the code behind right where I initialize the component, but I'm not sure how to make a VM a current one.


EDIT: Or do I define that datacontext = viewmodel in the selector?

Comment: I improved the answer, please go through